# Understanding java generic method

Tags: java, generics

Output is always `In OBJECT`. since the return type is void in all cases.
But why is it not going to m1(Integer s)? And without typecasting is it possible to make the call go to m1(Integer s)?

```
package test;

public class test_class {

public static void m1(Integer s){
    System.out.println("IN INT");
}

public static void m1(Object s){
    System.out.println("IN OBJECT");        
}

public static <Integer> void m2(Integer t){
    m1(t);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    test_class.m2(12);
}

}
```

Comment: What do you think `<Integer>` in `public static <Integer> void ` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: <Integer> --> Shouldn't this tell the compiler to call the m1 which accepts 'Integer'? Since Integer is subclass of Object(probably) I can understand why the call goes to Object, but if I delete the m1(Object s) the code does not compile.

Comment: That's a method declaration. It doesn't _call_ anything. Have you learned about generic methods yet and how they declare generic type parameters?

Comment: @Akash_Bandyopadhyay No, `<Integer>` creates a named generic type (and that then shadows `java.lang.Integer`). Why are you making that a generic method? And why did you name the type `Integer`?

Comment: You only *named* the generic type `Integer`. To illustrate, these two declarations are the same: `<Integer> void m2(Integer t)` and  `<Foo> void m2(Foo t)`

Comment: Okay, that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to understand how generics work, you somehow mix it up with overloading. If you declare a generic method, the type parameter (in your case `Integer`) is be a variable (often `T`). In your case, the type parameter is called Integer, which somehow interferes/shadows the type of the argument.

Just remove the `<Integer>` from `m2` and you get the expected result.

Comment: In addition to that you can cast the variable to control the execution of the right method, e.g. `Test.m2((Integer)Integer.valueOf(12));` or `Test.m2((Object)Integer.valueOf(12));`. That technique calls polymorphism.

Comment: I tried that. But it still goes to m1(object s), however if I cast it to integer inside definition of m2, then it works.